# How can use VIM's Command-T without arrow keys?

Tags: vim

I'm using VIM (not MacVim) along with the famous [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T) plugin. I'm used to using the hjkl instead of the arrow keys, but Command-T seems to require using the arrow keys for selecting a file from the list. Is the any way to make Command-T work with hjkl as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<C-j>` and `<C-k>`.

If there's a way to recognize the command-t window it could be possible to create a mapping for `j` and `k` only for that window.

Comment: Actually it makes sense to use `<C-j>` and `<C-k>` because when using Command-T we of course need the regular `j` and `k` for the fuzzy search! Thanks for your answer!